# Prestashop - Header links

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop

I have a Prestashop installation and am trying to add pages to it. I want the pages to show up with the HOME and CONTACT links and not in the information block. I take it I need to edit code, but where? Do I hard code the pages? Or can I create the page with the CMS in tools and just add a link in the headerlinks for that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH, I found it. For any who may also be looking for this, you can edit this directly like this:

Find the 'modules/blockpermanantlinks/ directory and edit the blockpermanentlinks-header.tpl file. You will need to set up target pages manually too. I just pointed to information CMS pages I made earlier.

Comment: I have a question, I've been trying to do the same, but NOTHING  happens on the site either when I edit the tpl files in the module directory or when I move the modules directory to the theme dir. wtf? :<

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan, in PS 1.4, you need to let Smarty Force a Compile in order to see changes you make while testing or changing the elements/appearance of a page.

Go to `Preferences > Performance`, and change to Force Compile: Yes, w/ Cache: No, while you are testing changes. When you are done, change those two settings back to Force Compile: No and Cache: Yes.